# C++ Union fields not set correcly

Tags: c++, unions, unassigned-variable

I have a templated union type NodeType. 
The problem is that upon assignement of its variable field are not set properly and when subsequently accessed the contain garbage values. Specifically, the problem occurs with _field1 and _field2 - see the main.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


        template <class T>
        struct structExampleType                
        {
          T _structField;
          typedef structExampleType<T>* pointerStructExample;
        };


         enum TYPE_tag
         {FIELD1_tag, FIELD2_tag} TYPE_tag; 

          template <class T>//, class P>
          union NodeType
          {
           enum TYPE_tag _nodeType_tag;
           char _field1;
           typename structExampleType<T>::pointerStructExample _field2;

           NodeType(){_field2=0;}

           NodeType(enum TYPE_tag nodeType_tag, char _charField)
           {
            _nodeType_tag=nodeType_tag;
            _field1=_charField;
            //_field2=0;
           }  

           NodeType(enum TYPE_tag nodeType_tag, typename structExampleType<T>::pointerStructExample pointer)
           {
            _nodeType_tag=nodeType_tag;
            _field2=pointer;
            //_field1='-';
           }          

          };







int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NodeType<int> node1, node2;
    structExampleType<int>* structExamplePointer;

    structExamplePointer=new structExampleType<int>();

    structExamplePointer->_structField=100;
//    structExamplePointer->_field2=structExamplePointer;

    node1=NodeType<int>(FIELD1_tag,'-');
    node2=NodeType<int>(FIELD2_tag,structExamplePointer);    


    cout<<endl<<"node1: ";    
    if (node1._nodeType_tag==FIELD1_tag)
    {cout<<node1._field1<<endl;}
    else
    {cout<<node1._field2<<endl;}        


    cout<<endl<<"node2: ";
    if (node2._nodeType_tag==FIELD2_tag)
    {cout<<node2._field1<<endl;}
    else
    {
        cout<<node2._field2<<endl;
        cout<<(node2._field2)->_structField<<endl;
    }  



    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

What can be the issue? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You're using an uninitialized pointer. I don't see why a pointer is necessary at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `main` you have these two lines:

```
structExampleType<int>* structExamplePointer;

structExamplePointer->_structField=100;
```

Remember that local variables are not initialized unless they have a default constructor (which pointers do not have), so in the second you dereference the uninitialized pointer `structExamplePointer`, leading to undefined behavior.

You also seem to misunderstand the purpose of `union`, as you try to set multiple fields. In a `union` all fields *share* the same space, so when writing to one member then all members are changed. Only the last written to member is valid. Trying to use other fields may again lead to undefined behavior.

---

If you need to have a "tag" field *and* other data, a structure containing the tag and the union data should be your choice:

```
struct NodeType
{
    enum TAG_Type
    {
        FIELD1,
        FIELD2
    } type;

    union
    {
        char field1;
        struct some_struct* field2;
    }
};
```

Comment: I would change the wording of "local variables are not initialized at all". `std::string s; //empty string`

Comment: @chris How about now?

Comment: Yeah, it's better. You could still technically do something like `int i{1};`, but for the sake of the OP's code, it gets the point across. Initialization rules in general aren't relevant.

Comment: ok fixed other assignments. From other answers, the point is that I am supposed to make just one assignment per union variabe.

Comment: @geraldCelente, And only use the one that was last set.

Comment: @problem is that I store this data in a stack, later on in my code I have no way of knowing what type is stored in each variable instance...

Comment: @geraldCelente Then you should have a structure containing the tag field and the union of the other data. See my updated answer for an example.

Answer (score 2):

With a `union` the members try to occupy the same space in memory so your constructor is causing the problem by assigning to each of the members and overwriting each other.

> The union is only as big as necessary to hold its largest data member. The other data members are allocated in the same bytes as part of that largest member.

Comment: Ok I get there. However the problem is that I need a mechanism for saving the type of variable stored in the union, and this information should be saved in the union itself. Any idea of how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

What you actually have here is not a union of field1 and field2, but rather a union of { tag, field1, field2 }. That's why you see garbage. Union is still a single memory area, but you set it three times over in your construction logic.

You might start with simpler cases and read some documentation, e.g., http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxy4b7b.aspx

To achieve your goals, you might do something like that (you need your tag to be external to the union):

union MyUnionType
{
   int data_int;
   double data_double;
}

typedef enum { IntTag, DoubleTag } UnionTypeTag;

class MyVariableClass
{
   private:
     MyUnionType m_variableField;
     UnionTypeTag m_variableFieldType;
}

Another approach is to design your code so that at any point in the code path you know what "flavor" of union type you're handling.

My personal opinion is that the latter (always knowing what is your union "flavor") was in minds of K&R when they thought of the union concept.

Comment: Ok I get there. However the problem is that I need a mechanism for saving the type of variable stored in the union, and this information should be saved in the union itself. Any idea of how I can achieve this?

Comment: I am not questioning your design here (maybe union is just not the right solution to your problem). So, if we leave the design aside, your "tag" should be external to the union itself. I'm updating my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please initialze you pointer `structExampleType<int>* structExamplePointer` before using it.

As dereferencing an un-initialized pointer is what is causing the problem

Comment: ok done. From other answers, the point is that I am supposed to make just one assignment per union variabe.